# Surjection between left and right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $i$ be an inverse map between left and right cosets
$$ i : L _H(G) \to R _H(G) $$
$$ i : (gH) \to  Hg^{-1} $$
where $G$ is group and $H$ is subgroup of $G.$
I want to prove surjection.
Let $ h g^{-1} \in R _H(G) $ , $ \exists h^{-1} g \in L _H(G)  $
$$  i (g h^{-1}  ) = (g h^{-1} )^{-1} $$
$$ = h g^{-1} $$
Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: You really shouldn't write $(Hg)^{-1}$ because that might not be an element of a group.

Comment: Your reasoning isn't correct.  You should start with a right coset $Hx$ as an element and then product a left coset (namely $x^{-1}H$) that will map to it.  This doesn't involve little $h$s.  Note that $h^{-1}g$ is NOT a left coset, so writing that it belongs to $L_H(G)$ is incorrect.

Comment: By the way, the actual hard part of this is showing that your map is well-defined in the first place.  The rest is automatic.

Comment: @Randall I corrected typo it is $ (gH)^{-1} $

Comment: Writing $(gH)^{-1}$ makes no sense unless $H$ happens to be normal.  (Even then it is not necessary for this.)

Comment: what if I just write $ Hg^{-1} $

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: thanks @Randall

Comment: The elements of $R_{H}(G)$ are sets of the form $Hg,$ not group elements of the for $hg.$ For every $Hg\in R_H(G),$ show $i(g^{-1}H)=Hg.$ The hard part (relatively) is to realize you need to show $i$ is well-defined. That is, if $g_1H=g_2H,$ then $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}.$ It’s not hard to prove, but understanding you need to prove this is the tricky part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ Hg \in R_{H} (G) $ , $\exists g^{-1}H \in L_{H} (G) $ such that
$$i ( g^{-1}H ) = H ({g^{-1}} )^{-1} = Hg$$

To prove that map is well defined. Let's $ g_{1} H$ , $ g_{2} H \in L_{H} (G) $ such that
$$ i ( g_{1} H ) =  i (g_{2} H) $$
$$  Hg_{1} ^{-1} = Hg_{2} ^{-1}$$
$$  H  = Hg_{2} ^{-1} g_{1}$$
$$\implies g_{2} ^{-1} g_{1} \in H$$
$$  g_{2}^{-1}  g_{1}  H =H $$
$$  g_{1}  H =g_{2}H $$

Comment: This part is written correctly.  However, you have yet to establish that the map $i$ is well-defined.

Comment: @Randall is it correct now

Comment: Yes!............